# Set timer in VBS

Tags: vbscript

I want to modify the script to launch the calculator app for 2 minutes then close it. The script can launch the app only. Please help.

```
    Set colMonitoredEvents = GetObject("winmgmts:")._
    ExecNotificationQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PowerManagementEvent")
    Do
    Set strLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    If strLatestEvent.EventType = 4 Then 
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")
    For Each objItem in colItems
    If objItem.name = "Calculator.exe" then objItem.terminate
    Next
    ElseIf strLatestEvent.EventType = 7 Then 
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run "calc.exe", 1, false
    End If
    Loop
```

I want to modify it to launch and close the calculator.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is accomplished simply with `Sleep` and `TaskKill`. Note that, starting probably with Windows 8, the calculator is a UWP app and `Calc.exe` is used to launch it, but `Calculator.exe` is the process name to kill it. On Windows 7, it would be `Calc.exe` for both.

```
Set oWSH = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
oWSH.Run "Calc.exe", 1, False
WScript.Sleep 120000 'two minutes
oWSH.Run "TaskKill /im Calculator.exe /f", 0, False
```

If you want to retain the capability of the original script, which kills calculator when the computer goes to sleep and restarts it on wake, and add a two minute delay before the kill, that would be done like this:

```
Set oWSH = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set colMonitoredEvents = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecNotificationQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PowerManagementEvent")
Do
  Set strLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
  If strLatestEvent.EventType = 4 Then
    WScript.Sleep 120000 'two minutes
    oWSH.Run "TaskKill /im Calculator.exe /f", 0, False
  ElseIf strLatestEvent.EventType = 7 Then 
    oWSH.Run "calc.exe", 1, False
  End If
  WScript.Sleep 500
Loop
```

Note that I added a .5 second delay in the loop to prevent unnecessary CPU load.

Comment: Hi LesFerch, Your simple works. Thanks. Instead of set timer, what the script should be if pressing any keys to terminate the calculator program

Comment: There's really no way to do that in VBScript. You can check for a key press in an HTA, but that would require the HTA window to have focus. Maybe take a look at [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: I follow the suggestion to modify my code but it does not work. Please help.

Comment: @echo off
for /F "skip=2 tokens=2*" %%A in ('reg query "HKLM\Software\microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v "EnableLUA"') DO (Echo %%B)

If %%B==0x0 (
reg add HKLM\Software\microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /D 1 /f
echo 1 %errorlevel%
) else (
reg add HKLM\Software\microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /D 0 /f
echo  0 %errorlevel%
)

for /F "skip=2 tokens=2*" %%A in ('reg query "HKLM\Software\microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v "EnableLUA"') DO (Echo %%B)

Timeout 5

Comment: I think you meant to post that batch file to [your question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1716007)